# How to read binary content of a file in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am very new to Flex. I want to retrieve file's binary content using flex but failed. Here is the code so far:

```
// ActionScript file

package source.fileApi{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;

    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import mx.utils.URLUtil;

    public class FileAPIMain {
        private var debug:Boolean = false;
        private var dataReaded:String;
        private var fr:FileReference;

        public function FileAPIMain():void{
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("setDebug", setDebug);
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("onLoadFileClick", onLoadFileClick);
            ExternalInterface.call("FileReader.__onFlashInitialized");
        }

        public function log(message:String):void {
            if (debug) {
                ExternalInterface.call("FileReader.__log", encodeURIComponent("[FileReader] " + message));
            }
        }

        public function setDebug(val:Boolean):void {
            debug = val;
            if (val) {
                log("debug enabled");
            }
        }

        public function onLoadFileClick():void{
            //create the FileReference instance
            fr = new FileReference();

            //listen for when they select a file
            fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelect);

            //listen for when then cancel out of the browse dialog
            fr.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL,onCancel);

            //open a native browse dialog that filters for text files
            fr.browse();
        }

        private function onFileSelect(e:Event):void{
            fr.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelect);
            //listen for when the file has loaded
            fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);

            //listen for any errors reading the file
            fr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadError);

            //load the content of the file
            fr.load();
        }

        private function onCancel(e:Event):void{
            log("File Browse Canceled");
            fr = null;
        }

      private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void{
        fr.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);

        //get the data from the file as a ByteArray
        var data:ByteArray = fr.data as ByteArray;

            dataReaded = data.readUTFBytes(data.bytesAvailable);

            ExternalInterface.call("FileReader.__getSize", fr.size);
            ExternalInterface.call("FileReader.__getName", fr.name);
            ExternalInterface.call("FileReader.__getData", dataReaded);
      ExternalInterface.call("FileReader.__takeAction");

            //clean up the FileReference instance
            fr = null;
        }

        private function onLoadError(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
            log("Error loading file : " + e.text);
        }
   }
}
```

But this did not give me the binary content of the file.. Could any one please tell me how to retrieve the full binary content of the given file using Flex (I am using FP 10.0).....

Comment: Use FileReference.browse() , and listen for complete event. Then just use readByte() from the filereferernce.data

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu readByte() returns only one byte but I need the full binary content, could you please provide some coding in the answer section...

Answer (score 0):

If you user FLashPlayer 10+ then make use of FileReference.

See the pure AS3 sample below

```
var buttonShape:Shape = new Shape();

buttonShape.graphics.beginFill(0x336699);
buttonShape.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 25);

var button = new SimpleButton(buttonShape, buttonShape, buttonShape, buttonShape);

addChild(button);

var fileRef:FileReference= new FileReference();
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
  fileRef.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png")]);
  fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
}

function onFileSelected(e:Event):void 
{
  fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
  fileRef.load();
}

function onFileLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
   // here we get the data
   var theData:Object  = e.target.data;

   // next you can manipulate the data as you like! ;) depending on the type
}
```

Comment: @AdrianPivulescu your above code is generated an Object like ByteArray. But I need the file Content in binary mode. please help...